# Thorntail with Hotswap agent possible?

Tags: wildfly-swarm, thorntail, hotswapagent

Is it possible to configure thorntail (swarm) runner plugin to use HotSwap Agent somehow? I've managed to do so with Wildfly but when I set VM arguments for the agent I get following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hotswap.agent.util.classloader.HotswapAgentClassLoaderExt`